# Numerical treatment of Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

I previously investigated the difficulty in rewriting the Riemann hypothesis and we concluded that it might be possible with a new transform.

Now I'm going to do a B Sc project at my university and might propose some mathematical programming. Could it be an idea to treat the Riemann hypothesis numerically (with matlab, R, pynum or similar tools), for example trivially just numerically check all the zeroes up to a very large number?

Comment: Checking the non-trivial zeros are all on $Re(s) = 1/2$ is complicated, [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903742/testing-zeros-of-the-riemann-hypothesis/1903768#1903768) : For checking the RH up to $Im(T)$, It requires estimating precisely the [$Z$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_function), counting its number of zero-crossings $[0,T]$, and then $\log \zeta(s)$ on $[2,2+iT] \cup [2+iT,1/2+iT]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in 2004, Gourdon and Demichel computed over 10 trillion zeroes, and checked other zeroes with heights up to $10^{24}$. Although your idea is not a new approach, it would certainly be worth your while to write a code which checks the non-trivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function. Good luck!